# TPROXY interferes DNAT port forwarding rules

Tags: iptables, transparent-proxy, nftables, dnat, vyos

I'm setting up TPROXY on my VyOS router to forward certain traffic to a local transparent proxy. It works pretty well, until I discovered that all of my DNAT port forwarding rules are no longer working (connection timeout when connecting from external network).

**Environment**

- Router: `10.0.0.1/24` (Proxy is running on `1234` port and adding SO_MARK with `0xff`)
- Internal Host: `10.0.0.2/24` (Port `80` should be exposed to the public)

**TPROXY Rules**

```
ip rule add fwmark 1 table 100
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100

nft add table myproxy
nft add chain myproxy prerouting { type filter hook prerouting priority 0 \; }
nft add rule myproxy prerouting ip daddr { 127.0.0.1/32, 224.0.0.0/4, 255.255.255.255/32 } return
nft add rule myproxy prerouting meta l4proto tcp ip daddr 10.0.0.0/24 return
nft add rule myproxy prerouting mark 0xff return
nft add rule myproxy prerouting meta l4proto { tcp, udp } mark set 1 tproxy to 127.0.0.1:1234 accept

nft add chain myproxy output { type route hook output priority 0 \; }
nft add rule myproxy output ip daddr { 127.0.0.1/32, 224.0.0.0/4, 255.255.255.255/32 } return
nft add rule myproxy output meta l4proto tcp ip daddr 10.0.0.0/24 return
nft add rule myproxy output mark 0xff return
nft add rule myproxy output meta l4proto { tcp, udp } mark set 1 accept

nft add table filter
nft add chain filter divert { type filter hook prerouting priority -150 \; }
nft add rule filter divert meta l4proto tcp socket transparent 1 meta mark set 1 accept
```

**DNAT Rules**

$ nft list table nat

```
table ip nat {
    chain PREROUTING {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
        iifname "pppoe0" tcp dport { 8080 } counter packets 7 bytes 400 dnat to 10.0.0.2:80
    }
}
```

**Symptoms**

Connecting `RouterPublicIP:8080` is timing out. Ideally it should forward traffic to `10.0.0.2:80`.

I guess inbound DNAT traffic is erroneously forwarded to the proxy (instead of the actual host `10.0.0.2`), however I couldn't figure out the correct nft rules.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding additionally `meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 10.0.0.0/24 return` to `myproxy prerouting` (before the `tproxy` rule, of course).